# Doing Row products conditionnally to value of specific columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset of this form.

```
a=data.frame(A=1:5,B=1:5,matrix(seq(50),nrow = 5))
colnames(a)<-c("A","B", paste0(1:10))
    A   B   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
    1   1   1   6   11  16  21  26  31  36  41  46
    2   2   2   7   12  17  22  27  32  37  42  47
    3   3   3   8   13  18  23  28  33  38  43  48
    4   4   4   9   14  19  24  29  34  39  44  49
    5   5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
```

I am intending to use apply in order to do the product of rows conditionnally to the value of A and B. Let's take row 2 for instance, we have A=2 and B=2 then the code will be looking for column="2" and column="2+2" and will do the product of all the elements of the selected vectors, Result is thus equal to 7*12*17=1248. 
I can  do it for a row

```
prod(a[1,match(a$A[1],colnames(a)):match(a$A[1]+a$B[1],colnames(a))])
```

but can't figure a way to apply it to all the data.frame. Any help?

Comment: The code with `prod` is giving an error

Comment: Yes missed the ], my fault.

Comment: Also, `2 + 2 = 4` and in the data, column name with 4 value is 17 for row 2.  So my doubt, is it  `7 * 12 * 17` because A is 2 and the column name with 2 starts at 7

Comment: If you are subtracting 1, then for first row, A is 1, then it becomes 0, right?

Comment: WIth your definition, I guess `apply(a, 1, function(x) {i1 <- match(x[1], names(x)); i2 <- match(x[1] + x[2], names(x)); prod(x[i1:i2])})`

Comment: Totally agree i will correct it, thanks

Comment: Your function seems to be  working; Thanks for your feedback! For the calculation error, it was a problem in importing the data, i took also the index columns. !

Comment: So i guess there is no substracting to do, the data frame i shared is wrong i will correct it

Comment: @akrun it is done thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `apply`,specify the `MARGIN` as 1 to loop over the rows,, create the index to `match` the column names from the first two elements (`A`, 'B`), create a sequence (`:`), subset the values of 'x' and get the`prod`

```
apply(a, 1, function(x) {
       i1 <- match(x[1], names(x))
       i2 <- match(x[1] + x[2], names(x))
        prod(x[i1:i2])
    })
#[1]          6       1428     150696   17535024 2362500000
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215782/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-doing-row-products-conditionnally-to-value-of-spec).